# Using Image instead of Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, canvas

I have a Image and I want to paint on top of it some square. But I keep getting undefined function on `getContext('2d')`. I must add that the var img is an image which is already loaded on the page, I'm trying to interpret it as a canvas since I am using another script which lets to select areas on the image and if I use a canvas the script will not work. So in the case where I can not interpret a image as a canvas what would you suggest?

Js function

```
function drawInput(dx1,dy1,dx2,dy2) {
    var img = document.getElementById('home:tempImg');

    var canvas = img;
    console.log(canvas);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(imageObj, dx1, dy1,dx2-dx1,dy2-dy1);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'images/selected.png';
}
```

HTML

```
<h:body>


    <h:form onsubmit="#{getComponents.getAllComponents()}" id="home">

        <div>

            <p:graphicImage id="tempImg" rendered="true" value="#{imageView.selectedImg}">
            </p:graphicImage>

        </div>
</h:form>
</h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myJSONStr ='{ "area" : #{areaInputView.areaListString}}';

        console.log(myJSONStr);


        var json = JSON.parse(myJSONStr);
        //console.log(json.area[1].x1);
        for(var i=0;myJSONStr.length >i ; i++) {
            console.log(json.area[i].x1, json.area[i].y1, json.area[i].x2, json.area[i].y2);
            drawInput(json.area[i].x1, json.area[i].y1, json.area[i].x2, json.area[i].y2);
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to come up with a new approach entirely. AFAIK you can't use an `img` as a `canvas`. What you can do is draw an image inside of a canvas. Its going to be a little more work, and you'll have to find a way to access `#{imageView.selectedImg}` inside a script; but its definitely possible. I'd suggest reconsidering your approach.

Comment: Hey Jordan, thanks for the response. Is there no way you can consider the dimensions of an image and paint another one on top of it but in the boundaries of the firs image dimensions?

Comment: You can definitely do that - I'm not immediately sure how, but take a look at the MDN docs around [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) and [Canvas.drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#Drawing_images). Capture a reference to the original image, and use its properties as bounds. If I find time today, I'll try and whip up an example for you.

Comment: Thanks, you don't have to, but if you want go ahead. Thanks for the tips ! :)

Answer (score 1):

By leveraging custom JS 'classes' (of the type `app.Image` in this case), we can build a pretty neat wrapper that allows us to draw images dynamically based on other instances we have kept track of.

Check out **[this Codepen](http://codepen.io/JordanForeman/pen/VYLXPa)** for a working example.

```
window.app = window.app || {};
app.Canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
app.Image = function(source, x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.data = new Image();
  this.data.addEventListener('load', this.draw.bind(this));
  this.data.src = source;
};

app.Image.prototype.draw = function() {
    app.Canvas.drawImage(this.data, this.x, this.y);
};

app.Image.prototype.getImageBounds = function() {
    return {
      height: this.data.height,
      width: this.data.width
    }
};

var myImage = new app.Image('http://placehold.it/250x250', 10, 10);
var mySecondImage = new app.Image('http://placesheen.com/100/100', myImage.x + 10, myImage.y + 10);
```

The most important line is the last one. Notice how we're initializing a new `app.Image` with `x` and `y` coordinates *relative* to the first image. By using a custom wrapper class that keeps track of this information, we're able to easily access the necessary data that we need in a variety of circumstances.

I hope this helps to get you on the right track! Let me know if you have any questions about the code, and I'll be glad to explain.

Comment: Nice answer! Here's an alternate idea that replaces the original img element with a canvas element: http://jsfiddle.net/w1srxtyk/

Comment: @markE that's awesome! Much simpler, and definitely more in the spirit of the original question. I'd suggest making an answer out of that :)

Comment: marKE if the image will be replaced with a canvas, I will not be able to use my selection script since it only allows select images not canvases.
@JordanForeman Thanks a lot, I will try implement your code. Hope it will suite fine. :) EDIT: I checked the example code. As i said I can not use canvas there in the example a canvas tag is in use

Comment: @FancyPants. Fair enough. You could "complete the circle" by creating a new img element and use the canvas as an image source: `myNewImage.src = canvas.toDataURL()` and then replace your original  img element with myNewImage.

Comment: `value="#{imageView.selectedImg}"` selectedImg is rendered when from home you select an image in the row. It renders it from byte code which it gets from the db. So it must be generic. I thought maybe you can assign the value to the canvas and then use the canvas as an img or something like that, but i don't believe that's possible

Comment: You might be able to create a transparent canvas with a higher `z-index` than the image (but with the same size/positioning) and then draw on that - keeping the img element intact, but also giving you the ability to leverage canvas drawing

Comment: I'm confused about your requirements, but I offer this: http://jsfiddle.net/vx3tcscc/

Comment: @JordanForeman Already tried to put the transparent canvas on top of the image. The selection script(which i use to select individual areas of the image) does not work, since the script is seeing a canvas instead of an image.

Comment: @markE I have an image, on that image I use a selection script to select individual areas. The selected area values go to the database. I need to retrieve them from the database and populate the img with squares to show that those areas are selected. But I did not find a way to draw an img on a img, just found many script to draw on canvas and I can not use a canvas,why? my upper comment answers to that question.